# How do you test a function argument with the wrong type in ts-jest?

Tags: typescript

I am testing a function written in TypeScript. To avoid having to compile my project every time, I am using `ts-jest`.

There is a caveat, though, that I am not sure there is a workaround for. I've checked the [`ts-jest` options](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/) without much luck. The function allows only a string for input.

```js
function tsFunc(arg:string){
  if (typeof(arg)!=='string'){ 
    throw new TypeError('....')
  } 
}
```

But I can't test it since using `tsFunc(5)` won't compile in the test files.

How do you test this?

Comment: `// @ts-ignore` it?

Comment: I may try, but is that a good work around ? can't believe there isn't anything out there for this purpose @jonrsharpe

Comment: What do you mean _"good"_? There is something out there for this purpose, and that is that thing - when you want to tell the compiler "no don't type check this", that's ignoring it. You could do e.g. `5 as any`, but that doesn't seem "better".

Comment: Also you should note that [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is **not** a function - it's an operator, the parentheses are redundant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well a way to disable arguments type checking from the config file

Comment: That would definitely be worse, this way you're only disabling it in specific cases in the tests where you know that's the appropriate behaviour, if you turned it off for the whole project why use TypeScript? But maybe `tsFunc` shouldn't be typed as `arg: string` - if you need the runtime check then you know there are cases when it can get called with things that aren't strings, so the signature should reflect that.

Comment: "a way to disable arguments type checking from the config file" no no no. This is not a good idea. The vast majority of your tests should use the function's correct types. This is a very good thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see...I guess I only want to test JS, but the compilation is quite demanding to compile+test, maybe I should try to compile only files that changed

Comment: @AlexWayne, yes, you're right, that was dumb but still...this doesn't convince me..

Comment: Without some more context it's hard to say, but generally testing the TypeScript is fine. Test cases that aren't type-safe should be the exception. Interfaces should reflect usage - if that function _could_ get called at runtime with a non-string, the compiler is not in a position to validate that (i.e. it's at the "edge" of your program where data comes from outside) it probably shouldn't be typed as `arg: string`. If it _can_ be typed as `arg: string`, the runtime check is redundant anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is just in case the user would be distracted and run it with a *number*. I had never thought about that, but maybe I should include, at least in some cases, a type that doesn't make sense to me but the user would use?

Comment: I mean at a certain point you have to ask whose fault and problem that is - if you're shipping type-checked code and the accompanying declarations and the end-user ignores them, they have to take _some_ responsibility!

Comment: @Minksy most of the time if a user of your library is ignoring your documentation AND not using Typescript, and then get a cryptic error, that's IMHO sort of on them. There's exceptions to this of course, and it really depends on how you expect your library to be used and what data source you expect to as inputs and how much validation that may require.

Comment: @jonrsharpe & Alex thanks to both.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you specifically want to test arguments that violate the the type contract of the function, then you need to cast that argument to `any` to basically tell Typescript to disable type checking on that variable.

```
expect(() => {
  tsFunc(123 as any);
}).toThrow();
```

Or you could add a `// @ts-expect-error` comment.

```
expect(() => {
  // @ts-expect-error testing wrong argument type
  tsFunc(123);
}).toThrow();
```

Which to use is up to you. But somehow you need to tell Typescript that you are doing something wrong on purpose.

Comment: I didn't know about `@ts-expect-error`, that **is** better than `@ts-ignore`.

Comment: if you can include all the options I may accept it, ts ignore and expect error are useful too,

Comment: `//@ts-expect-error` is only allowed if there actually is an error, so it's preferred to `//@ts-ignore`. This eslint rule is nice https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-ts-comment/ is nice.

Comment: @Minsky I would not recommend `//@ts-ignore`. `//@ts-expect-error` is better since it requires there to actually be a type error, which will save you headaches when you refactor this code 6 months from now.